# connection - could not find sbo that match the connection string

Tags: sapb1

Im getting this error, connection - could not find sbo that match the connection string(66000-85), when i edited an active form in Business One studio and then want to preview it in the Client. I use SAP Business one version 10

Answer (score 0):

Normally when I encounter this problem it is because I have forgotten to set the platform to the matching 32/64 bit version of SAP i am using.

[image: Configuration Manager]

to find the version of SAP go to Help > About SAP Business One
[image: SAP About]